# T-SQL puzzle: pass each row of a table as an input to an Inline Function and develop a new stacked dataset using UNION ALL

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, union-all, inline-functions

I have a unique and rare situation in T-SQL. This seems to be sort of a puzzle.

1) I have (an input) dataset, say `X`, with `7` rows and just one column called `YearMonth`:

**DataSet X**:

```
YearMonth    
2018-08    
2018-09    
2018-10    
2018-11    
2018-12    
2019-01    
2019-02
```

Essentially the `YearMonth` represents months between `Aug 2018` to `Feb 2019`.

2) I have an Inline User Defined Function (Inline Function) called `dbo.fn_zzwwhh`:

This Inline Function returns a table with about 10 columns and two rows, taking an input such as `2018-08`. The Inline Function is called in the following manner:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh (@YearMonth)
```

Essentially this Inline Function `dbo.fn_zzwwhh` takes a `YearMonth` value, say `2018-08`
and returns two rows and ten columns. It always returns two rows and ten columns
even for other inputs such as `2018-09`, `2018-10`, `2018-11`, `2018-12`, `2019-01`, `2019-02`.

Now, my situation is this:

I need to develop a new dataset, say dataset Z, with the following output:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2018-08')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2018-09')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2018-10')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2018-11')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2018-12')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2019-01')    
UNION ALL    
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_zzwwhh ('2019-02')
```

This dataset `Z` is needed for my SSRS report.

Can anyone let me know on how to pass EACH row from dataset `X` (one at a time)
into the Inline Function `dbo.fn_zzwwhh`, and develop the dataset `Z`, using `UNION ALL` between each passed in input value ?

I would greatly appreciate if you could provide me a solution.

Comment: Ummm, how about using dynamic SQL?

Comment: @MarkKram CROSS APPLY would by the way to go for something this simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use `CROSS APPLY`?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT YearMonth
    FROM X 
) a
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_zzwwhh(a.YearMonth)
```

Comment: I think it works. Thanks Eric. Am testing the code, appreciate your response

Comment: Thanks CROSS APPLY is indeed the solution